# Gatling: How to setUp and tearDown scenario

Tags: stress-testing, gatling

I have a Gatling test which should do the following:

1. create user once
2. retrieve user's data according to specific load model. Actual load testing.
3. delete user after when done

Question: how to emulate this with Gatling? If I chain calls like :

```
val scn = scenario("Test scenario").exec(_create-user_).exec(_retrive-user_).exec(_delete-user_)
setUp(scn).protocols(httpConf))
```

then creating and deleting user will be part of the test.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the `before` and `after` hooks to create and delete the user.

```scala
class RetrieveUserSimulation extends Simulation {

  before {
    // create user
  }

  setUp(scn).protocols(httpConf)

  after {
    // delete user
  }

}
```

You'll have to issue the create and delete HTTP requests manually. `before` and `after` take `=> Unit` thunks, not `Scenario`s.

Comment: I tried something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63386159/gatling-exec-outside-scenario-scope-post-requests-are-not-called but I don't see POST requests only the one in the scenario

Answer (score 0):

In before hook we can call a method which can have below code.

```
val httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create.build
val httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpPut(urlString))
println("StatusCode - " + httpResponse.getStatusLine.getStatusCode)
httpClient.close()
```

We can use HttpGet as well. Here used apache library

```
example : org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
```