# Gatling exec outside scenario scope - POST requests are not called

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am trying to write gatling performance test where I am using the **before** and **after** blocks of the Gatling Simulation to make one-time HTTP post requests against the service.

```
 class MyTest extends Simulation {
      
      // Some code here
      // and definitions
      
      val myScenario = scenario("Vary number of ...")
        .exec(PublishMessageRoundRobin(pConfigTest, testTitle + "-" + numX, numY))
    
      // extract the nodes  
      val nodes : Array[String]  = endpoints.split(endpointDelimiter)  
      
      //
      // create consumers with desired configurations at endpoint prior to scenario run
      // then start them
      //
      before {
          var endpoint = ""
                
          //
          // TODO: based on run parameter, decide if we should pre-run producers
          // 
          for( elt <- 1 to numX ) {
            endpoint = "http://" + nodes(elt-1) + cEndpoint + setConfig      
            CallSet( myobj, endpoint )
            endpoint = "http://" + nodes(elt-1) + cEndpoint + start  
            CallStart( myobj, endpoint )        
          }
      }
      
      if (testMode == "debug") {
        setUp(
          myScenario.inject(
            atOnceUsers(1)
          )
        ).protocols(httpConf)    
      } else if (testMode == "open") {
        setUp(
          myScenario.inject(       
            rampConcurrentUsers(20) to (200) during (durationInMinutes minutes),
          )
        ).protocols(httpConf)
      }
       
       // stop all consumers
       after {
           var endpoint = ""
           for( elt <- 1 to numX ) {
               endpoint = "http://" + nodes(elt-1) + cEndpoint + stop  
               CallStop(myobj, endpoint)
           }
       }
    
    }
```

CallStart and CallStop and CallSet are not making POST request for some reason.
The only POST request called is the one defined within the scenario `PublishMessageRoundRobin` which calls exec and creates post against endpoint.

they are defined very similar way here is one of them

```
def CallStop(consumerConfig : ConsumerConfig, stopEndpoint : String ) = { 
      
      val jsonBody = consumerConfig.asJson
      val valuedJsonBody = Printer.noSpaces.copy(dropNullValues = true).print(jsonBody)
      println(valuedJsonBody)        
      println("stopEndpoint-" + stopEndpoint) 

      exec(http("StopConsumer-" + stopEndpoint)    
      .post(stopEndpoint)    
      .header(HttpHeaderNames.ContentType, HttpHeaderValues.ApplicationJson)
      .body(StringBody(valuedJsonBody))
      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(bodyString.saveAs("serverResponse"))
      )    
    .exec { session =>
      println("server_response: " + session("serverResponse").as[String])
      session
    }
  }
```

I see the println statements above but there is no POST request. Can someone help explain what is going on?

**EDIT**
I am new to Gatling and Scala so I am not sure how to debug or have breakpoints. It seems that it fails silently which is concerning to me.

Comment: looks like from here https://gatling.io/docs/3.2/general/simulation_structure/?highlight=simulation under Hooks section - can't use Gatling DSL

Comment: it silently fails - which is big problem - no warning - no error / nothing... it just ignores DSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://gatling.io/docs/3.2/general/simulation_structure/?highlight=simulation) - Gatling DSL doesn't work inside hooks. I wish there was a warning or something to not waste time on that.

I had to perform the actual POST request without using Gatling DSL as below.

```
 def CallStop(consumerConfig : ConsumerConfig, stopEndpoint : String ) = { 
          
          val jsonBody = consumerConfig.asJson
          val valuedJsonBody = Printer.noSpaces.copy(dropNullValues = true).print(jsonBody)
          println(valuedJsonBody)        
          println("stopEndpoint:" + stopEndpoint) 
    
          val post = new HttpPost(stopEndpoint)
          post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
          post.setEntity(new StringEntity(valuedJsonBody))
          // send the post request
          val client = new DefaultHttpClient
          val response = client.execute(post)
    
          println("Response:" + response)
      }
```